# Why are many of the roofs in North Korea blue?

Tags: north-korea

I know it might not directly be related to politics, but I wonder if it has any significant political meaning? Out of curiousity, I was looking on many cities in North Korea using Google Maps, and I [noticed many blue roofs](https://www.google.com/maps/place/North+Korea/@39.0213147,125.7868679,2747m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x357e02dae64f4337:0x3a0b871c3e1d861c). Any ideas why? Are they military facilities? Living quarters for military and officials?

Comment: Big discussion here: http://www.reddit.com/r/korea/comments/160w7n/why_are_there_so_many_structures_with_blue_roofs/ My guess: NK has limited choices of suppliers for materials. I'd guess that the primary roofing product used there just happens to be blue. I don't think there's any political connotations here.

Comment: I'm surprised we can see North Korea on Google at all.

Comment: @Bregalad You can make Google see North Korea, but you can't make North Korea see Google. :)

Comment: @Bregalad, what are they going to do to stop Google? They haven't given them anything that they can threaten to take away.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about politics

Comment: are you serious? Anything about North Korea is politics. It is not like asking why roads are black... And I must point out - this question was answered - and the answer was accepted - over two years ago!!! Are you seriously bored? Are you collecting votes and points for an upcoming SE elections?

Answer (score 14):

I'm no expert on Korean culture, but this appears to have been asked many places on the internet already.

Blue tiles appear to be status symbol historically in Korean culture. Insofar as someone can afford blue tiles, they must be wealthy.

This imagery is also present in South Korea; their head of state lives in "the [Blue House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_House)" which also has these blue tiles. Image from wikimedia:
[image]

According to [this post](https://community.futuremark.com/forum/showthread.php?76956-Blue-Roofs-(North-Korea)), during the 1970's North Korea's government had a modernization effort. As part of this, the government mass purchased construction supplies to be used across the country. It's possible that many of these buildings were constructed at this time and in the same style.